# Kotlin/Native: How to instantiate an IntVar?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

The `IntVar` constructor takes a `NativePtr` as an argument.

How do I create an `IntVar` from `Int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
memScoped {
  val intVar = alloc<IntVar>()
  intVar.value = 123
}
```

Check out [value](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/value.html) for more information